# Use linear model for propensity score matching (R MatchIt)

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I want to use the propensity score fitted from a linear model to match observations using the [MatchIt](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/index.html) library.

For example, suppose `df` is a dataframe. If I were to balance its `treatment` column in terms of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` using the propensity score from a logit, I would set `distance = 'glm'` and `link = 'logit'`:

```
m <- matchit(formula = treatment ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
             data = df,
             method = 'nearest',
             distance = 'glm',
             link = 'logit')
```

## How can I do the same with a linear model instead of a logit?

As per the [documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/distance.html):

> When link is prepended by "linear.", the linear predictor is used instead of the predicted probabilities.

Hence, I tried:

```
m <- matchit(formula = treatment ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
             data = df,
             method = 'nearest',
             distance = 'glm',
             link = 'linear.logit')
```

I'm afraid that doing this (`link = linear.logit`) would use the score from the log-odds of the logit model.

Is there any way I can just use a linear model instead of a generalized linear model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this from within `matchit()` (and you shouldn't, in general, which is why it is not allowed). But you can always estimate propensity score outside `matchit()` however you want and the supply them to `matchit()`. To use a linear probability model, you would run the following:

```r
fit <- lm(treatment ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)
ps <- fit$fitted
m <- matchit(treatment ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
             data = df,
             method = 'nearest',
             distance = ps)
```